# deleting rows from tables and it's effects on the _id

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So i have this app I'm making for my school project. it has a custom listview with a custom arrayadapter and it's populated by clicking a button. here is the Room class

```
public class Room {

private int xBtn;
private int _id;
private int roomImage;
private String name;
private String type;

public Room(String name, String type, int roomImage){
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.roomImage = roomImage;
}
```

here is my DBHandling onCreate(), addRoom() and deleteRoom() Methods:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

public void addRoom(Room room){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, room.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_TYPE, room.getType());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public void removeRoom(String roomsName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + "=\"" + roomsName + "\";");
}
```

My questing is, let say, we have 5 rooms, room1(id=0), room2(id=1) and so on.
and i delete room room3(#2) will the new order become 0,1,3,4 or 0,1,2,3.
if it didn't become 0,1,2,3 , how can i make it work? and if it did become 0,1,2,3 , will the _id in Room itself change as well or will it only be changed in the table? In short, i want the _id in the class Room to adjust itself automatically with the id in the table. how do i make this work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. The ids are incremental and go only **forward**. You don't have to worry about that. And it is necessary for when you will have more tables related to this one.

Comment: And when you want to sort the list by name, the IDs in the list are 3,1,4,0. The position in the list has *nothing* to do with the ID value.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a primary key auto increment the first entry will be at 0 then 1 them 2 so on on if you update say row at id 1 it stays 1. Now let's say row row gets deleted,  but uh oh you need out back in.  It will bout be 2 or 3 or wherever is after your last id.

Comment: Yes it will be 1,3,4 ... it's still there in a sense.  It basically has a flash that says im all used up go on to the next guy. The only way to do that would be to auto increment both columns but out kinda depends on what yourtrying to accomplish